# Textbox to allow input to set currency when form is open

Tags: c#, input, textbox

For example, the letter G would choose GBP, letter U would choose USD etc.

I am trying to allow users to choose their currency when the form is open as shown below:

```
    private void Ccy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baseCcy1.Visible = true;
        baseCcy1.Focus();

        CcyForm c = new CcyForm((Button)sender, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, _Ccy);
        c.ShowDialog();

        setBuySellButtons();
    }
```

However, the textbox only focuses once the form is closed. It does not allow me to type in the textbox when the CcyForm is open. I have tried the async/await method with Task.delay, but this did not help. I do not wish to put the textbox in the CcyForm, but rather, be visible when form is open, and invisible when it is not.

How can I allow users to type in the textbox when the CcyForm is open? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the documentation clearly states, an application developer should not call `Focus` on a control, but rather `Select`.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. If anyone has an issue with this in the future, placing the code in a KeyDown method, and using the switch/case method will fix it. Also, setting KeyPreview to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `c.Show(this);`.  That will create an owned form or modeless dialogue.  That is a form that will always remain in front of its caller but will not block access to it.  An example of an owned form is the VS Find & Replace dialogue.

```
baseCcy1.Show();

var c = new CcyForm((Button)sender, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, _Ccy);

c.Show(this);
Activate();
baseCcy1.Select();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however this did not solve the issue :(

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  If you're not prepared to go into any detail beyond "it didn't work" then you're not helping yourself.

Comment: There's no point setting focus to the `TextBox` before creating and displaying the form because the form will take focus when it's displayed.  You need to focus the `TextBox` after the form has been displayed.  I figured that that would be a given but, looking at your original code, maybe not.

Comment: You also need to make the form containing the `TextBox` the active form.  See the code example in my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Use CcyForm.Show(); instead of CcyForm.ShowDialog();